# Xcode 5: It is giving me error messages when I add an action to my button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

here is my .h view controller file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ZKGameController : UIViewController

{




IBOutlet UIImageView *PlayerSprite;
IBOutlet UIButton *rightButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *leftButton;

NSTimer *animationTimer;

}


[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startLeftAnimation)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopAnimation)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopAnimation)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startLeftAnimation)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopAnimation)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopAnimation)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


- (void)stopAnimation;
- (void)frontBarrelAnimation;
- (void)barrelStartDown;
- (void)startLeftAnimation;
- (void)startRightAnimation;
- (void)animateLeft;
- (void)animateRight;

@end
```

It gives me error messages on the "leftButton addTarget:self..." blah blah blah.
I have search why and i have found no reason but it says "expected identifier or'(', Use of undeclared identifier "self" and "leftButton" and the same thing for the right button.

Here is my .m file if that helps: 
    #import "ZKGameController.h"

```
@interface ZKGameController ()

@end

@implementation ZKGameController

- (void)startLeftAnimation
{
    animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self     selector:@selector(animateLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)startRightAnimation
{

    animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self     selector:@selector(animateRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void)stopAnimation
{
    if(animationTimer != nil)
    {
        [animationTimer invalidate];
        animationTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)animateLeft
{
    PlayerSprite.center = CGPointMake(PlayerSprite.center.x - 1, PlayerSprite.center.y);
}

- (void)animateRight
{
    PlayerSprite.center = CGPointMake(PlayerSprite.center.x + 1, PlayerSprite.center.y);
}






- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before     navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

I have linked up all of my image views and buttons with the correct things but it gives me those messages. If you have any suggestions please help.

Comment: Don't put code in the .h file. All of those calls to `addTarget...` need to be in the .m file.

Comment: May I suggest you go find a good tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. It's important to learn the basics of the language before you attempt to write the next best-selling game.

Comment: you can't add the code in .h file it must implemented in the implementation file .m

Comment: Dear, you should learn basics of Objective C as rmaddy suggested you.

Comment: doesnt work in the .m file, it gives me the same error messages, how to i format it. Do i simply cut and paste or is there a special thing to it?

Comment: nevermind, i am actually quite adept at objective-c, but this is a concept that i never bothered to learn, thanks for the help

Comment: No offense but putting code in a .h file is not an indication of being adept. :)

Answer (score 0):

cut and paste that add target calls to your viewDidLoad method after 
[super viewDidLoad]; in .m file